# LDOs in series and impedance

Tags: impedance, ldo

I am unable to understand one thing. I have a 2 LDOs in series , the first a regular LDO with a normal impedance and second is a shunt regulator with an ultra low impedance .

What will my load see... the 2 impatiences added or only the last impedance (from shunt regulator)

Comment: What do you mean by a shunt regulator in series?. Add a schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be the last regulator in the chain with ultra low impedance. Do you have a schematic or part numbers for these regulators ?

Answer (score 0):

The Shunt regulator requires a high source impedance, or it cannot regulate.

I suggest you be sure there is a capacitor on LDO output, then a resistor between LDO/Cap to the Shunt regulator.